# Next.js - Confusion about cache duration

Tags: next.js

I was reading the documentation for the new Next.js App Router and I am confused about the cache behaviour for data fetching defined [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching)

In the section on deduping it states:

> On the server, the cache lasts the lifetime of a server request until the rendering process completes.

However right in the next section on static fetching it states:

> By default, Next.js automatically does static fetches. This means that the data will be fetched at build time, cached, and reused on each request.

So which is it? Does the cache last for the duration of the rendering process of a request or is it a permanent cache that is built at build time?